# force dark mode in android is not responding

Tags: android, android-theme

I am trying to implement dark theme as described [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme). So, I have created `arrays.xml` as:

```
<resources>
  <array name="themes_labels">
    <item>"Default"</item>
    <item>"Light"</item>
    <item>"Dark"</item>
  </array>

  <string-array name="themes_color">
    <item>"Default"</item>
    <item>"Light"</item>
    <item>"Dark"</item>
  </string-array>
</resources>
```

and this is my code to change the theme, which is not working, i.e., the theme is not changing, though the first Toast is giving correct value, where the 2nd Toast before switch gives some mysterious value like 16/32 etc.

I understand that, my value array is key, where I amy trying to read some int in the switch. But I am not getting how to get that.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String theme = sharedPref.getString("theme", "Default");
Toast.makeText(this, theme, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
int currentNightMode = getResources().getConfiguration().uiMode & Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK;
Toast.makeText(this, ""+currentNightMode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
switch (currentNightMode) {
  case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO:
    // Night mode is not active, we're using the light theme
    break;
  case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES:
    // Night mode is active, we're using dark theme
    break;
    default:
      AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM);
}
```

Comment: the value in the switch case will only tell user's current theme. You have not implemented the code which actually changes the theme.

Comment: Can you please show me how to do that?

Comment: https://www.journaldev.com/19352/android-daynight-theme-night-mode

Answer (score 1):

Try below dark mode code which I am use.

**Step - 1**

First of create **night** folder into your resource file like below image(i.e. values-night)

[image: Create night mode folder]

**Step - 2**

Create **styles,strings and colors** xml file for **night mode** same as below image and add your night mode color,string and style which you want to show in your app when night mode was apply.

[image: Create night mode xml files]

**Step - 3**

Add this below code in your splash screen if you want to **set night mode as per device mode** first time when application installed.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (!CommonUtils.isToogleEnabled(SplashActivity.this)) {
        if (CommonUtils.isDarkMode(SplashActivity.this)) {
            CommonUtils.setIsNightModeEnabled(SplashActivity.this, true);
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
        } else {
            CommonUtils.setIsNightModeEnabled(SplashActivity.this, false);
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
        }
    } else {
        if (CommonUtils.isNightModeEnabled(SplashActivity.this)) {
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
        } else {
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
        }
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...
    //your code
}
```

**Step - 4**

Add this below code in your all activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (CommonUtils.isNightModeEnabled(MainActivity.this)) {
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
    } else {
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...
    //your code
}
```

**Step - 5**

**Change mode** using below code

```
private WeakReference<Activity> mActivity;

binding.imgNightMode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        mActivity = new WeakReference<Activity>(MainActivity.this);
        CommonUtils.setIsToogleEnabled(MainActivity.this, true);
        if (CommonUtils.isNightModeEnabled(MainActivity.this)) {
            CommonUtils.setIsNightModeEnabled(MainActivity.this, false);
            mActivity.get().recreate();
        } else {
            CommonUtils.setIsNightModeEnabled(MainActivity.this, true);
            mActivity.get().recreate();
        }
    }
});
```

Below methods are **CommonUtils**.

```
private static final String NIGHT_MODE = "NIGHT_MODE";
private static final String TOOGLE = "TOOGLE";

public static boolean isNightModeEnabled(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences mPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("MY_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
    return mPrefs.getBoolean(NIGHT_MODE, false);
}

public static void setIsNightModeEnabled(Context context, boolean isNightModeEnabled) {
    SharedPreferences mPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("MY_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(NIGHT_MODE, isNightModeEnabled);
    editor.apply();
}

public static void setIsToogleEnabled(Context context, boolean isToogleEnabled) {
    SharedPreferences mPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("MY_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(TOOGLE, isToogleEnabled);
    editor.apply();
}

public static boolean isToogleEnabled(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences mPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("MY_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
    return mPrefs.getBoolean(TOOGLE, false);
}

public static boolean isDarkMode(Activity activity) {
    return (activity.getResources().getConfiguration()
            .uiMode & Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK) == Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES;
}
```

I hope this can help you!

Thank You.